# Error trying to install yowsup on windows

Tags: python, whatsapp, yowsup

I followed instructions as given [here](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup#windows)
I installed python 3.4.3, then installed zlib and finally executed `python setup.py install` after downloading extracting the yowsup from here[enter link description here](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup#windows)
and changed directory to yowsup-master.

But I get this error:

```
    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build\
temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\curve25519module.o: bad reloc address 0x14 in section
 `.data'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Then since above did not work, I tried using `pip install yowsup2` but I get the same error.
Could anyone get round this error?
I am not into python, so not able to tell why is this error happening.

I am on windows 8.1 64 bit.

Answer (score -1):

There are few things which don't let you import that yowsup module in windows even in windows 10. so i have managed to install that in linux os (i am using kali linux) i have tryed to download and install the visual c++ build tool but that is just waste of time and data.

So Better switch to a Cloud like heroku or sitch to linux (vm or duel boot)